# Derivative of indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to understand the following derivative, where $r\geq0$:

$$
\psi(r):=\int_r^\infty e^{-(y-r)}\Bigl(\int_0^y \psi(y-x)dx\Bigr)dy
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow\\
$$
$$
\psi'(r)=-\int_0^r \psi(r-x)dx +\int_r^\infty -e^{-(y-r)}\Bigl(\int_0^y \psi(y-x)dx\Bigr)dy
$$

More specifically, I was under the impression that, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the derivative of $\psi$ was simply the function inside the integral,
$$
e^{-(y-r)}\Bigl(\int_0^y \psi(y-x)dx\Bigr)
$$
evaluated at $r$. (Or rather, the negative thereof, since the $r$ was the lower bound.)

However, that would just be the first summand in the above result. The second summand I can't explain. Where does it come from? And where does my application of the FtoC fail?

Comment: Possibly the fundamental theorem application you're thinking of is one valid when the integrand does not depend on the function argument, $F(x) = \int_x^b f_1(t)\,dt$. The answer by user170231 applies the more general rule for $F(x) = \int_x^b f_2(x,t)\,dt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should follow directly from the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). With

$$\psi(r)=\int_r^\infty \underbrace{e^{-(y-r)} \left( \int_0^y \psi(y-x)\,\mathrm dx\right)}_{f(r,y)} \,\mathrm dy$$

the derivative would be

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d\psi}{\mathrm dr}&=-f(r,r)\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dr}+\int_r^\infty \frac{\partial f(r,y)}{\partial r}\,\mathrm dy\\[1ex]
&=-e^{-(r-r)}\int_0^r \psi(r-x)\,\mathrm dx + \int_r^\infty e^{-(y-r)}\left(\int_0^y\psi(y-x)\,\mathrm dx\right)\,\mathrm dy
\end{align}$$

though there seems to be a sign error either here or in the result you've provided.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275809/checking-the-result-of-symbolic-integro-differentiation#275811